# [Angular google-maps API]: Is there a way to change <agm-marker> atteributes from inside the typescript code?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps-markers

I am reading some markers from the database and rendering them on the `Google-maps` using the `<agm-marker>` tag.

This is the part of the code where I read the markers and push them into the `markers` array (`componentName.component.ts`):

```
 ngOnInit(): void {


this.markerService.fetchMarkers()

this.markerService.markersSubject.subscribe(markers => {

  markers.forEach(marker => {

    this.markers.push({
      lat: marker.latitude,
      lng: marker.longitude,
      title: marker.title,
      story: marker.story,
      path: marker.img_path
    })

  })

})

    } //onInit
```

and the Html where the markers are rendered:

```
    <agm-map
    [latitude]="latitude"
    [longitude]="longitude"
    [zoom]="zoom"
    [disableDefaultUI]="false"
    [streetViewControl]="false"
    [zoomControl]="false"
    [mapTypeControl]="false"
    [mapTypeId]="'terrain'"
    > 

    <agm-marker id="display-markers"
     *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
      (markerClick)="openModal('marker-content' + i)"
      [latitude]="m.lat"
      [longitude]="m.lng"
      [markerDraggable]="m.draggable"
      [iconUrl]="m.icon" 
      [visible]="true"
      [id]="i"
    </agm-marker>

   </agm-map>
```

I need to enable the user to clear all of the markers by a button press, meaning that the  `[visible]` attribute of `<agm-marker>` should be set to False for each of the markers. How can I access the markers from inside the `component.ts` file and change it?

Are there any other ways for clearing all of the markers from the Map in Angular?

I can not find anything online :(

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get the question completely, but i think that you need that:

### Html template

```
...
<agm-marker id="display-markers"
  ...
  [visible]="isMarkersVisible"
  ...
</agm-marker>
...
<button (click)="toggleMarkers()">{{isMarkersVisible ? "Hide" : "Show"}}</button>
...
```

### Ts file

```
...
isMarkersVisible = true;
...
ngOnInit(): void { ... }
...
toggleMarkers(): void {
  this.isMarkersVisible = !this.isMarkersVisible;
}
...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks. seems you really got the question! but is there a way to actually remove the markers and not just changing their visibility?

Comment: yes, just in `toggleMarkers()` method you need to clear an array of markers like `this.markers = []`. But it would be impossible then to return them back, unless you download them again from the server.

Comment: thanks. it worked. i can not believe i spent a whole day trying many complicated solutions when the answer was this easy and straightforward. thanks again

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that it helped.